# macOS calendar.app - app reset results in calendars reappearing

Tags: mojave, calendar

How do you delete all calendars app data and reset the app information to default.

Issue:

- I delete all the calendar data and reboot the system.  I open the calendar app and it has reset to the default calendars.  But then it resets again and loads the previous calendars that I deleted.  Not sure where it's finding it from since I thought I deleted all the locations the calendar app data resides.

Setup

- on macOS 10.14.6
- calendar Version 11.0 (2245.5.2)
- local sync only (no iCloud)

I have deleted the following:

- ~/Library/Calendar/

  ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.CalendarAgent

  ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.CalendarAgent.CalNCService

  ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.CalendarFileHandler

  ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.CalendarNotification.CalNCService

  ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.iCal.CalendarNC

Then I have rebooted the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after deleting the above folders and if the issue still exists enter the following terminal command

```
defaults delete com.apple.SyncServer SyncServicesResetWorldRunOnce
```

Then reboot the system.